# WHEN statement after another When statement

Tags: sql, events

I'm trying to use a double when statement but not sure how to do so. 
Here is the code I'm using

```
CASE WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=1 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text1
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=2 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text2
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=3 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text3
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=4 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text4
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=5 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text5
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=6 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text6
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=7 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text7
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=8 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text8
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=9 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text9
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=10 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text10
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=11 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text11
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=12 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text12
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=13 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text13
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=14 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text14
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=15 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text15
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=16 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text16
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=17 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text17
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=18 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text18
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=19 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text19
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=20 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text20
ELSE 'N/A' END
```

What I didn't taken account for is that `dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text[xx]` can be null which i want to do is in each `WHEN` statement after the `THEN` I would use another `WHEN ISNULL` to do write "See attachment" `ELSE` use the text if is not null. Not sure how to write that in. Keep getting care when i try to do a `isnull` or `when isnull` or `case when isnull` followed with `else`.

Answer (score 5):

Why not an `isnull` around the `case`? Also you can use the form of `case` where you select on a value instead of a condition:

```
ISNULL(CASE dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41
  WHEN 1 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text1
  WHEN 2 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text2
  WHEN 3 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text3
  WHEN 4 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text4
  WHEN 5 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text5
  WHEN 6 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text6
  WHEN 7 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text7
  WHEN 8 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text8
  WHEN 9 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text9
  WHEN 10 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text10
  WHEN 11 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text11
  WHEN 12 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text12
  WHEN 13 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text13
  WHEN 14 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text14
  WHEN 15 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text15
  WHEN 16 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text16
  WHEN 17 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text17
  WHEN 18 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text18
  WHEN 19 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text19
  WHEN 20 THEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text20
  ELSE 'N/A'
END, 'See attachment')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do an ISNULL() check.

```
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41=1 
THEN ISNULL(dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Text1, 'See attachment')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add one more statement?

```
WHEN dbo.CSEFExtWorkflowAbsences.Number41 is null THEN 'See Attachment'
```

That would work just fine.

Comment: The OP is saying that the expression in the `THEN` can also be null, and that's what he's trying to account for - not the `WHEN` condition.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I would do a second pass on this then, and check what the value was that it finally found.  Use this entire query as a derived table.